# How can I create a link to an absolute path in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.6

How do I create a link  to open an absolute path on a local or network UNC location?

The path is generated on-the-fly in a controller action. The path could be local (`c:\temp\abc\`) or on the network in a UNC location (`\\server\share\abc\`).

I tried using `@Html.Raw(Model.FolderName)` but it escapes the slashes and the links don't actually work. For me, the double slashes is an aesthetic issue but it could confuse non-technical users. I can workaround the escaped slashes by not displaying the path if the link opens  the location.

How can I display links in a razor view that when selected will open File Explorer / My Computer to the specified location?

Comment: this might help https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/539456/Exploring-a-folder-and-its-subdirectories-using-AS

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible open your local file explorer like this.

Links works in a way redirecting in browser.

In this case, my opinion is to create your own application protocol and set it in a way to open local file explorer with a path from argument.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx